# Matrix Representation of Linear Transformation from R2x2 to R3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

We have a linear transformation *T* : $\mathbb R^{2\times2} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{3}$ defined by
$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right)=(a+b,2d,b).$$
Let *A* and *B* be the ordered bases for $\mathbb R^{2\times2}$ and $\mathbb R^{3}$ respectively:
$$A=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$ and $$B=\left\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\right\}.$$
Find the matrix representation of the linear transformation $([T]_A^B)$.

It is still unclear to me how to operate on the two sets of bases to find the matrix representation of the transformation. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start calculating  the image of the basis $A$, for example for the first element of the basis we have $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right) = (1,0,0)$$ then write the element as a linear combination of the choosen basis for the Image. Hence the first column of the matrix representing $T$ is exactly $(1,0,0)^t$, and so on for all vectors of $A$.

Comment: I have tried approaching the problem this way. We get $(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(0,0,0),(0,2,0)$. Therefore, we get a $4\times3$ matrix. Problem is, now that I have the four vectors, I can put them in a matrix, but is that enough to describe *T*?

Comment: Yes, using the notation of @EmilioNovati, you can describe you matrix space just as any 4-dimensional space. In that case $T$ is essentialy a $3\times4$ matrix which is exactly the matrix you construct.

Comment: I was unsure about the correctness of the approach because I was trying to multiply the aforementioned matrix by another one to test whether the transformation would return the same result as the multiplication, but I had switched one of the $1$s with a $0$, and the results were obviously different.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that you are searching matrix with three rows and four columns, that transforms:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
a+b\\2d\\b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

can you find this matrix?